# Find is omitting some records from the table

Tags: cakephp, find, conditional-statements

I am basically trying to bring the last 5 records from a table.
The only catch is that I don't want some records with the same x_id to be brought since I would be repeating the x_id, so I pass a  'group' condition to achieve this.
However, when adding this new group condition, something odd happens and the result for the query is randomly omitting some rows of the table. So, randomly, some records are brought, and some are not. So some record which should have been brought is not.

For instance:
LAST 10 records in my table are: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0
After doing my query, I should have as a result: 0-9-8-7-6
However, at random, I get: 9-8-6-5-3 OR 0-8-7-6-4

Basically it skips some records the shit =//

```
$condicionesComentarios = array('conditions' => array('Comentario.aceptado' => 1), 'limit' => 5, 'order' => 'Comentario.id DESC', 'group' => array('Comentario.empresa_id'));

$ultimosComentarios = $this->Empresa->Comentario->find('all', $condicionesComentarios);
```

**UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION**

*Empresa hasMany Comentario*

Small portion of Comentarios table:

```
**id**     **empresa_id**
1           7
2           9 
3           3
4           1
5           1
6           4
7           8
8           5
```

EXPECTED RESULT: last 5 records from the table, without repeated empresa_id

query result-> (id = 8, 7, 6, 5, 3) *Note that row with id: 4 should be skipped, to avoid empresa_id repetition*

WHAT I GET: Some of the records are randomly skipped when they should not.

query result-> (id = 7, 6, 5, 2, 1)  *Note that here row with id: 8 should not be skipped, but it's nonetheless.*

Comment: What's `emprasa_id`, and why would there be duplicate values that would require `GROUP`ing?

Comment: Empresa hasMany Comentario
So in the Comentarios table, empresa_id relates with the Empresas table.
I want to bring the last 5, but without repeated empresa_id

Comment: remove group from ur query then post the result

Comment: If I remove the group condition I might get results with the same empresa_id
My goal is to get the last 5 records of Comentarios table, but those 5 cannot have the same empresa_id

Comment: It sounds like your question is less about cake and more about how to write the query in the first place.  Have you tried opening up a SQL editor and playing with your query to see how that impacts your results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joni you were almost right, put me on track. Your code perse was not working, though a small modification made it work properly:

```
$condicionesComentarios = array(
                          'conditions' => array('Comentario.aceptado' => 1), 
                          'limit' => 5, 'order' => 'max(Comentario.id) DESC', 
                          'group' => array('Comentario.empresa_id'), 
                          'fields' => array('max(Comentario.id)', 'Comentario.empresa_id'));
```

As you can see I had to modify the 'order' and add an extra condition to 'fields'.
Again what it does: brings the last 5 rows from Comentarios table, but without repeating the empresa_id field from within those last rows.

Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ORDER BY` is on one column (`Comentario.id`) and `GROUP BY` on another (`Comentario.empresa_id`).

From your description it sounds like you want to order by and group by the same column:

```
$condicionesComentarios = array(
    'conditions' => array('Comentario.aceptado' => 1), 
    'limit' => 5,
    'order' => 'Comentario.empresa_id DESC',
    'group' => array('Comentario.empresa_id'));
```

---

**UPDATE**: It sounds like what you want is MAX(id) from each group. In SQL you would use this query:

```
select max(id) from Comentarios where Comentario.aceptado
    group by empresa_id order by id desc limit 5;
```

In CakePHP you can write that as:

```
$condicionesComentarios = array(
    'fields' => array('max(Comentario.id)'),
    'conditions' => array('Comentario.aceptado' => 1), 
    'limit' => 5,
    'order' => 'Comentario.id DESC',
    'group' => array('Comentario.empresa_id'));
```

Comment: But with those conditions I would not be bringing the last 5 records of the table.
I want to bring the last 5 records of the table Comentarios, hence my doing of 'order' => 'Comentario.id DESC'
The purpose of the 'group' condition is to avoid having duplicated empresa_id within those last 5

Comment: The `order by` and `limit` ensure that you are bringing the last 5 records. If you are getting fewer than 5 you must have fewer than 5 distinct `empresa_id`s in your commentary table.

Comment: I just tried and it's still not working. It still omits some records from the table, at random.

Comment: Please update your question with a sample of your data and the expected output.

Comment: There I did, hope its clearer.
By the way, a friend told me the solution was in adding a 'field' condition, hand made. No idea what he means, nor how to do it.